# In MSBUILD, how can you specify a condition that check whether command line or VS launched it?

Tags: msbuild

I have a csproj that I would like to have trigger the opening of a particular file in Visual Studio, only if the target was executed from within Visual Studio, but not from the MSBUILD command line.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 37):

Quote from [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2017):

> When building inside Visual Studio, the property $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) is set to true. This can be used in your project or .targets files to cause the build to behave differently.

Example how it could be used in your .*proj or .targets file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyProperty Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'">This build is done by VS</MyProperty>
  <MyProperty Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true'">This build is done from command line of by TFS</MyProperty>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: New MSDN page:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/visual-studio-integration-msbuild?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 2):

Add a property to the .csproj project file, example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <FromMSBuild>false</FromMSBuild>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then in the task you want to run, put a condition that evaluates that property. For example, i f you want to open notepad.exe whenever the build is executed from command line and NOT visual studio:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
<Exec Command="C:\Windows\Notepad.exe" Condition="$(FromMSBuild)" />
  </Target>
```

Of course, this is dependent on setting the $(FromMSBuild) property correctly when you run the build via command line, like so:

```
MSBuild myProject.csproj /p:FromMSBuild=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to open a file when building in visual studio but not from command line with MSBuild?

If that is the case, specify a PreBuild or PostBuild in Visual Studio.

1. Right click on the project in the solution explorer and select *Properties*
2. Select the *Events* tab
3. Add either a Pre or Post Build event to open the desired file

Comment: no -- I have a csproj with custom msbuild targets in it. When I click build in Visual Studio, I want it to result in a special action taking place in the target... something like Condition="StartedInVS()".  When I run it from command linke (ie msbuild ...) I want that condition to fail.  So how can MSBUILD detect in a target how/what called the target?

Comment: You are right, my apologies. My previous answer is wrong, and the build events would be executed regardless. I added another answer that explains how to accomplish your goal, and I tested it this time to be sure.