# setting to know if Visual Studio Solution/project is being build from command line or IDE

Tags: msbuild

I have A Visual Studio 2012 VC++ project (executable) that uses a dll from another VC++ project. It build successfully on IDE, when I add following code to 
Project->Build Events-> Pre-build event

```
call setupdll.bat
```

where *setupdll.bat* sets the environment variable for dll as

```
set COMSPEC = "%VCINSTALLDIR%\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
setx PATH "..\..\lib\libsndfile;..\..\lib\simulink"
```

The only caveat is that once the project builds, I need to close VS IDE ,reopen again to be able to run the project successfully due to environment variable addition of specified path taking place in next session.

Now, when I need to build the solution on a build server that does not have  a Visual studio installed, I execute batch script "*MySol.bat*" that uses msbuild.exe for build process. However, in this case, I do not include "*setupdll.bat*" in the Project property Project->Build Events-> Pre-build event
but rather execute following as part of "*MySol.bat*"

```
PATH=%PATH%;"..\..\lib\libsndfile;..\..\lib\simulink"
```

This works fine too.
However, this means every time I have to build the solution using IDE,I include the "*setupdll.bat*" file in properties, while on build server, I do not.
I tried following solution based on
[StackOverflow Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591214/in-msbuild-how-can-you-specify-a-condition-that-check-whether-command-line-or-v)

but it did not work.
Specifically, I did the following
Modified project xml to add property "*FromVS*"

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug_File|x64'">
<FromVS>true</FromVS>
<TargetExt>.exe</TargetExt>
<OutDir>$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\</OutDir>
<PreBuildEventUseInBuild>true</PreBuildEventUseInBuild>
```

When I call the VS IDE, I modified the PREbuildEvent as

```
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug_File|x64'">
<PreBuildEvent>
  <Command>call setupdll.bat Condition="$(FromVS)"</Command>
</PreBuildEvent>
```

and when calling from "*MySol.bat*", I use

```
call %MSBuildToolsPathVS%/msbuild %SolfilePath%  /p:configuration=debug_File;Platform=x64;FromVS=false^ 


/t:build
```

However, when I build from MSbuild,  I can still see that 
"*setupdll.bat*" is called. 
Is there something wrong I am doing or do i need to change some other settings?
Any other suggestions?

Thanks
Sedy

Comment: possible duplicate of [In MSBUILD, how can you specify a condition that check whether command line or VS launched it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591214/in-msbuild-how-can-you-specify-a-condition-that-check-whether-command-line-or-v)

Comment: @Jimmy I tried using link that you mentioned but it did not work.I have updated the question accordingly